# Angular 2 material not working with electron

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, electron

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Desktop App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/overlay.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="assets/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <base href="./">
</head>

<body>
  <app>
    Loading
  </app>
  <script src="js/ajax-d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ajax-nvd3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/desktop.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I load this html on browser material floating label is working fine but when i load it with electron it stops working ..

It should work like

[image]

but its working like

[image]

please help !!